# Terminating a scheduled thread in Spring

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

The default implementation of Spring `@Scheduled` annotation spawns a single threaded task executor.

The problem is that sometimes methods cannot stop properly and release the thread which leads to downtime.

One possible solution is to implement `SchedulingConfigurer` interface like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
class Application implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)
    }

    @Override
    void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor())
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100)
    }
}
```

This solution creates a security buffer of 100 threads, but does not solve the problem.

**How to terminate a method (annotated with `@Scheduled` and cron expressions) after specific timeout?**

Comment: Quartz is a much better task execution framework. It also fits very well into spring's DI model. You should consider using it.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738755/how-to-timeout-a-spring-boot-scheduled-thread)