# How to set a timeout in the Scheduled task of Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, timeout, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Springboot to develop a web server.

In my project, I need to execute some task periodically so I used the Scheduled:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

public class TextFilter {    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5 * 60 * 1000) // 5min
    public void updateSensitiveWords() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

As you see, the function `updateSensitiveWords` will be executed after 5 minutes when the last execution has finished.

However, I need to worry about the case, where the execution may spend too much time for some reason, e.g. 20 min. So I think I need to set a timeout for the function, something like this:

```
public class TextFilter {    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5 * 60 * 1000, timeout = 2 * 60 * 1000)
    public void updateSensitiveWords() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Which means that if the execution of the function spends more than 2 min, abort/stop the execution and wait for the next time.

What is the proper way to do so? Does Springboot provide some mechanism to do so?

Comment: Hey Yves... Good evening!
Did you have found any solution for this question? 
I have the same problem now...

Comment: @Jefferson No I haven't. For now I simply set `fixedDelay` as the execution of my task won't spend more than 2 min in most of cases... As my understanding, we have to develop our custom TaskScheduler for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found another question that may be related to yours here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31740351/10297961

the answer suggested you should try to implement some ThreadPoolTaskScheduler config to control your scheduler